# Toshiba Satellite L500 / RTL8191SE wifi very slow and unstable

Tags: drivers, wireless

I'm on Toshiba Satellite L500 with Ubuntu 14.04 and the wifi is very slow & unstable.

```
$ lshsw |grep -i wireless
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8191SEvB Wireless LAN Controller
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192se driverversion=3.19.0-32-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Are there any solutions for this?

(The connection is fast and steady with both my other Linux devices => it must be a driver issue).

Comment: Before anything else make sure you have the recommended wireless settings at your router: WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. There's no point in further troubleshooting without assuring the connection isn't crippled at the source.

Comment: Thanks. It must be a driver issue. The connection is fast and steady with my other Linux devices.

Comment: I could be but not necessarily. Check wireless encryption settings and change it accordingly. This should be done regardless of other devices being fine (or apparently fine) as this improves the connections for all, hence the *Before anything else...* The driver hypotheses is less plausible because your chipset is old and well supported since many Ubuntu releases ago. Some tweaking may improve the overall performance but it needs an expert to pinpoint exactly what to change (disabling power management, enabling/disabling hardware encryption, etc.)

Comment: My router settings are and were as you describe (WPA2-AES with a preshared key).

Comment: OK, good. As I said before, you need an expert.